# Google Docs File properties

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-workspace

We have a requirement to pull document properties and show in the document is there any option available to show using apps script or we can show from the document out of box features.

```
var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
documentProperties.setProperty('DAYS_TO_FETCH', '5');`

var property = { key: 'department', value: 'Sales', visibility: 'PUBLIC' };   
Drive.Properties.insert(property, "fileid_xxxxxx");
```

Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: Please update the question with a [minimal and complete code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What document properties? User created? Or other? There are several mechanisms to accomplish this, but it needs to be more specific.

Comment: var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
documentProperties.setProperty('DAYS_TO_FETCH', '5');                                       it is used to set property of the document. we want to access those properties in the document using any identifiers

Comment: This still isn't clear. What _exact_ properties are you trying to find for a document? Do you want it displayed in the doc as part of the body? Or do you want a popup using `DriveApp`?

Comment: we need to use those properties in the document

Comment: var property = {
    key: 'department',
    value: 'Sales',
    visibility: 'PUBLIC'
  };
  Drive.Properties.insert(property, "fileid_xxxxxx");                                                        it is used to insert file property, we need to access those properties from the document

Answer (score 0):

Getting properties is the reverse of setting properties. You can set a property on a document (which includes spreadsheets or slides) using something like in your question:

```js
function storeProps() {
// create the object
// Keys can also store object values
var props = { "key1": "Some string, "key2": "Another string" };

// Store the Document property, limited to the active document
PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperties(props);
}

// You can also add a single property
PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("key3", "Yet another string");
```

Once the properties are stored, you can use the same API to access the entire `Property` object in a loop or via key value.

```js
function getProps() {
  // Get the document properties
  var storedProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties(); // returns an object

  // Option one: open via key if you know the key
  storedProps.getProperty(key1) // returns "Some string"

  // Option two: get the {Property} object and loop for whatever
  storedProps.getProperties() // returns { "key1": "Some string", ... }
}
```

[The Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) is quite detailed and includes code examples. Be sure to check there for more detailed method documentation.